# Format inline output conditional on textual context

Tags: r, formatting, knitr, sweave

Using a modification (adapted from Jason French's blog post [here](http://www.jason-french.com/blog/2014/04/25/formatting-sweave-and-knitr-output-for-2-digits/)) to the default inline `knitr` hook, I am printing numeric output rounded to 3 decimal places. If the value is less than 0.001, it returns "< 0.001".

Here's an MWE showing the hook modification, and how I might use it in practice in R Markdown:

````
```{r setup, echo=FALSE}
library(knitr)
inline_hook <- function(x) {
  if (is.numeric(x)) {
    res <- ifelse(x == round(x),
      sprintf("%d", x),
      sprintf("%.3f", x)
    )
    res <- ifelse(x < 0.001, '< 0.001', res)
    paste(res, collapse = ", ")
  } else paste(as.character(x), collapse = ", ")
}

knit_hooks$set(inline = inline_hook)
``` 

```{r, echo=FALSE}
stat <- 1.2345
p <- 0.000001
```

Blah was significant (test statistic = `r stat`, p = `r p`)
````

The above renders as:

```
Blah was significant (test statistic = 1.234, p = < 0.001)
```

Note the `p = < 0.001`. Preferably, this would be `p < 0.001`. Is it possible to have `knitr` check whether an equals sign precedes the inline expression, and if it does, suppress it when appropriate?

In case it makes a difference, I'm actually knitting a Sweave document, not R Markdown.

Comment: "Is it possible to have knitr check whether an equals sign precedes the inline expression[?]" No, I don't think so. Would a solution without the inline hook (but comparably simple to use) also be OK?

Comment: @CL. - I had thought I might have to fall back on defining a function, `fun`, that returns the rounded value(s) as a character string, with the appropriate `=` or `<` prepended. And then call it when necessary, e.g. ```Blah was significant (test statistic `r fun(stat)`, p `r fun(p)`)```, and don't call the `fun` when values are desired without a leading `=`/`<`. Is that what you had in mind? I'm open to any solution, but obviously the simpler (and more readable), the better.

Comment: That's exactly what I have in mind, yes. You can use the hook for normal numbers like `stat`, only for p-values you'd use `fun(p)` (or with more funny naming `p(p)`).

Comment: @CL. - feel free to post an example for posterity, and if no simpler solution turns up, I'll accept (and I think you're right.. the expressions can't be aware of the surrounding text... I could `readLines('file.tex')`, `gsub` the `= <` out, and write out again before knitting, but that seems pretty clunky...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I don't like the `inline_hook` used in the question / the linked blog. Automatically converting output like this seems risky to me. The current question is a case in point: Sometimes the conversion is harmful.

There is a trivial and a somewhat complex solution to the issue.

### Trivial solution

The hook can be circumvented using `asis_output`:

```
`r asis_output(0.0001)`
```

outputs `1e-04`, i.e. the hook doesn't apply. Otherwise the output was `< 0.001`.

Drawback: You either use the hook, but then you dont know whether you get `[number]` or `< [number]` as output (which is a problem when you want output like "p = [number]" / "p < [number]"). Or you use `asis_output`; then you know there will be no (in-)equality sign, but you cannot take advantage of the hook.

### Advanced solution

The following function applies `inline_hook` but adds an additional `=` sign if the hook doesn't add `<`:

```
le <- function(x) {
  rel <- if (x >= 0.001) "=" else ""
  return(asis_output(paste(rel, inline_hook(x))))
}
```

This has the following advantages:

1. The hook can be used.
2. There always is an (in-) equality sign.

Note that `le` is not vectorized.

**Examples:**

````
```{r setup, echo=FALSE}
library(knitr)
inline_hook <- function(x) {
  if (is.numeric(x)) {
    res <- ifelse(x == round(x),
                  sprintf("%d", x),
                  sprintf("%.3f", x)
    )
    res <- ifelse(x < 0.001, '< 0.001', res)
    paste(res, collapse = ", ")
  } else paste(as.character(x), collapse = ", ")
}

knit_hooks$set(inline = inline_hook)

le <- function(x) {
  rel <- if (x >= 0.001) "=" else ""
  return(asis_output(paste(rel, inline_hook(x))))
}

```

* p `r le(0.01)` (value: 0.01)
* p `r le(0.001)` (value: 0.001)
* p `r le(0.0001)` (value: 0.0001)
* p `r le(0.00001)` (value: 0.00001)
````

**Output:**

```
p = 0.010 (value: 0.01)
p = 0.001 (value: 0.001)
p < 0.001 (value: 0.0001)
p < 0.001 (value: 0.00001)
```